# Function that gives 1 only when an integer is divisible by another integer

Tags: nt.number-theory

I need a function that takes two inputs, a and b, and returns 1 only when a is divisible by b and 0 otherwise. Can this be written in a nice mathematical way (other than using indicator functions)?

Comment: Try cosine and floor function.

Answer (score 5):

In analytic number theory, this function is usually written as
$$ f(a,b):=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{n=1}^b e^{2\pi i na/b}.$$
This works in practice.

**Added.** To respond to Andrej Bauer's comment, "in practice" means that if we encounter a complicated sum with a divisibility condition like $b\mid a$, then we detect this condition by inserting the above subsum. This is the first thing that we try in analytic number theory. For a random example, see how Tim Browning derives (3.1) from the previous display via (2.9) in [this arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2385.pdf).

Comment: What exactly does "in practice" mean here? Like, if you're in the desert and need to figure out whether 15485863 divides 2778545904897799?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: See my "Added" section. (P.S. Trust analytic number theory.)

Comment: Excellent, I am glad to see the trick is useful outside of a desert as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(a,b)=\operatorname{floor}(\cos^2(\pi a/b))$$
But I guess most people would write
$$f(a,b)=\begin{cases}1 &;\text{if } b\mid a \\ 0 &;\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$